# Firbase приложение не работает без Android Studio

Tags: android, firebase

Если создать apk и перенести его на устройство, то приложение не проходить авторизацию(через гугл). Если запустить его из   Android Studio, то работает нормально. 
При авторизации(на устройстве) выдает сообщение:

> Google sign in failed. Status{statusCode=unknown status code: 12501, resolution=null}

Спасибо!

Comment: apk релизной версии переносите вручную?

Comment: @temq, да  переношу на устройство, потом устанавливаю. Дополнил вопрос.

Comment: Релизная и дебажные сборки, обычно, подписываются разными ключами. Соответственно у вас, скорей всего, в фаербасе прописан только дебажный ключ. Вам надо прописать ещй релизный ключ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Релизная и дебажные сборки, обычно, подписываются разными ключами. Соответственно у вас, скорей всего, в firebase прописан только дебажный ключ. Для корректной работы необходимо так же прописать ключ, которым подписывается релизная, или любая другая сборка.